# Forms with label checkbox, checking only first checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
<form>
    <label for="cPendrive"><input type="checkbox" name="wyposazenie[]" value="Pendrive" id="cPendrive"/><span>Pendrive</span></label>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4e9tjtL9/

I have problem, then press anything checbox/label always is selected only first checkbox, not checkbox inside form.

Where is problem?

I would like not use javascript and generate random names for atrribute 'for' and 'id'.

Comment: you have command id's for all checkboxes, change it to classes, ID should be unique.

Comment: @Mritunjay — The `for` attribute of a label keys off the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. An id must be **unique** in a page.

When you click on a label, the browser looks for the element with the matching id. It stops after it is found it (so it always finds the first one).

Make your ids unique.

> I would like not use javascript and generate random names for atrribute 'for' and 'id'.

You don't have to use JavaScript (you can use any programming language on the server, or at build time, or you can write them by hand) and the values don't have to be random (a sequential number on the end will do fine).

Comment: Ok, because I thinked, that ID can be that same in form. But is right, that ID must be unique in a page.